# how can I install "pip wheel" on a machine without internet connection?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-wheel

We have a prod server machine without internet connection, and I would like to be able to execute "pip wheel".

I've downloaded `virtualenv-1.9.tar.gz` copied to the prod server and extracted it. First, why isn't pip wheel available right away?

```
[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ ./virtualenv-1.9/virtualenv.py venv/v1
New python executable in venv/v1/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ source venv/v1/bin/activate
(v1)[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ which pip
~/venv/v1/bin/pip
(v1)[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ pip wheel
ERROR: unknown command "wheel" - maybe you meant "help"
```

I've proceeded to download and copy `wheel-0.24.0.tar.gz`, but that only installed `wheel`, not `pip wheel`:

```
(v1)[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ pip install wheel-0.24.0.tar.gz
Unpacking ./wheel-0.24.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///x/home/ihadanny/wheel-0.24.0.tar.gz
    no previously-included directories found matching 'wheel/test/*/dist'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'wheel/test/*/build'
Installing collected packages: wheel
  Running setup.py install for wheel
    no previously-included directories found matching 'wheel/test/*/dist'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'wheel/test/*/build'
    Installing wheel script to /x/home/ihadanny/venv/v1/bin
Successfully installed wheel
Cleaning up...
(v1)[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ pip wheel
ERROR: unknown command "wheel" - maybe you meant "help"
```

EDIT: I also tried `pip install wheel` to no-avail

```
(v1)[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ pip install wheel
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wheel in ./venv/v1/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Cleaning up...
(v1)[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ pip wheel
ERROR: unknown command "wheel" - maybe you meant "help"
```

and of course `upgrade` can't work (no internet connection...)

(v1)[ihadanny@lvshdc2en0012 ~]$ pip install --upgrade wheel
   Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

what am I missing?

Comment: `pip install wheel` ?

Comment: Thanks @plg but that doesn't do the trick as well..

Comment: To me looks like you need a different version of pip. Which version you are using ? Also you cannot use `pip install wheel` without a connection.

Comment: oops! thanks @Marcs, apparently I'm using the pip bundled with virtualenv-1.9, while I should be using the latest virtualenv-1.11.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use that virtual env if you update pip, but better to update a to the latest virtualenv. If you don't have a connection download the [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/wheel/wheel-0.24.0.tar.gz#md5=3b0d66f0d127ea8befaa5d11453107fd) source package, extract it and use:

> pip install wheel-0.24.0/

Don't omit the final slash.

Comment: Thanks, the root cause was my classic mistake of not noticing 1.9 < 1.11 :)